# How to copy value from database1.table1.column1 to database2.table1.column1 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 similar databases with the same structure and different values in SQL Server.

I want to copy the values of one column of the table from the first database to the second database in the same table and column

```
database1.table1.column1 = database2.table1.column1
```

Thank you

Comment: if your 2 database are in the same instance, you can do a simple `UPDATE` statement

Comment: If different server then create linked server and use 4 part naming convention like linkedserver name.dbname.dbo.table name. If same server then use 3 part naming convention like dbname.dbo.tablename

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dordi
how can update
can you write the query?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example query to perform an update:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.column1 = t1.column1
FROM database1.table1 t1
INNER JOIN database2.table1 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO db2.schema2.table2 (col2)
    SELECT col1
    FROM db1.schema1.table1
GO
```

Where:

- `col1`: the column you want to copy
- `col2`: the column you want to insert the copied data into

But, before that, you will need to create the `col2` and they should be the same data type.